# RestKit: Nested data but no relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm trying to parse the GitHub API with RestKit, and specifically the commits of a repository.
You can see in [their documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) that there are nested attributes, like the "commit" hash. There attributes, though, are part of the main object and I wouldn't want adding a new model and a relationship for this.

How can I add a mapping to the commit message there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the kind of Core Data model you're trying to get, but from what I understand maybe you could just flatten the API resource and set the `message` as a direct attribute of your `commit` object.

Something like this:

```
[commitMapping mapKeyPath:@"commit.message" toAttribute:@"commitMessage"];
```

Comment: Yay ! I was sure there was something like this. But didn't know I could just split with dots. Thanks :)

Comment: Kind of hijacking the question, but please bear with me. It seems that this answer is not working anymore in RestKit 0.2, since mapKeyPath:toAttribute: method is not available. What's the right way to do this now?